# Conditional regex php

Tags: php, regex

I'm facing some problem with php regex but after many researches (conditional regex, subpattern regex), I still can't solve it.

I have a folder that contains many images and based on variable value I have to go to that folder and select all images that match the value.
e.g: In my folder I have 3 images:

```
p102.jpg ; p1020.jpg ; p102_1.jpg;
```

I only want the regex to select :

```
p102.jpg ; p102_1.jpg
```

but with the regex below It selects all 3 images.

```
$image_to_find = 102;
$path = "[^\d]*.*/"
$test = "/^[a-zA-Z]?$image_to_find".$path;
foreach(glob($file_directory) as $file){
 if(preg_match($test, $file)){
   match[]= $file;
 }
}
```

I also try:

```
$path = "(?:\_[0-9]?).*/"; (it selects only p102_1.jpg)
```

Can you help me to figure it out. thanks
(sorry for the english)

Comment: Why do you want it to select those two images, what is the rule that you are trying to build.

Comment: is there always a letter at the beginning?

Comment: @Casimir the letter doesn't appear always. mayo code is working. I also replace $path="[^\d]*.*/"  by $path="[^\d]/" and it working. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

You can avoid the foreach loop if you use the glob pattern:

```
$num = 102;

$result = glob($path . '[a-zA-Z]' . $num . '[._]*');
```

Note: if you need to allow several different formats, you can use `array_merge` and several glob patterns: `array_merge(glob(...), glob(...));`

If you want the first letter optional:

```
$result = array_merge(
    glob($path . $num . '[._]*jpg'),
    glob($path . '[a-zA-Z]' . $num . '[._]*jpg')
);
```

or better, use the brace option:

```
$result = glob($path . '{[a-zA-Z],}' . $num . '[._]*jpg', GLOB_BRACE);
```

That stays a better alternative than the combo "foreach/preg_match" (or `preg_grep`) if filenames are not too complicated.

With `preg_grep`:

```
$pattern = '~(?:^|/)[a-z]?' . $num . '(?:_\d+)?\.jpg$~i';
$result = preg_grep($pattern, glob($path . '*' . $num . '*.jpg'));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
/p102[_\.]\d*\.?jpg/g
```

https://regex101.com/r/hM4oE0/1

Where p102 should be your 'image_to_find' var.

Comment: Yup, I came up with something similar but you were faster. I tested yours and it works.

Answer (score 0):

Not tested, should work.

```
$find = 102;
$pattern = "/p". $find ."(?:_\d+)?\.jpg/";
$list = array();

foreach (glob($file_directory) as $file)
{
    if (preg_match($pattern, $file))
    {
        $list[] = $file;
    }
}
```

regex: http://regexr.com/3bp29

Answer (score -1):

Tested and working:

```
<?php
$image_to_find = 102;
$pattern = '[a-zA-Z]' . $image_to_find . '[._]*';
$path = '/your_folder/your_subfolder/';
$file_directory = glob($path . $pattern );
echo '<pre>';
var_dump($file_directory);
echo '</pre>';
exit();
```

I hope this helps!